# How to filter based on a field in the custom through model using rest serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models with many to many relation. The many2many table is created and linked to the parent tables by the 'through' attribute.

```
ModelA(modles.Model):
  name = charfield()

ModelB(models.Model):
  subject = charfield(default=1, choices = [1,2,3])
  people = ManyToManyField(ModelA, through="MOdelAB")

ModelAB(models.Model):
  status = integerfield()
  modela_id = foreignkey()
  modelb_id = foreignkey()
  
ModelB_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
  modela = ModelASerailizer(many=True)

  class Meta:
      model = ModelB
      exclude = ...
      fields = ...
      depth = 1
```

This returns all the A objects in the through table, but I want to filter only the ones with status=99.

Is there a nice way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the `related_name` field so that you can get accessed the through field from the `ModelA`.

```
ModelB(models.Model):
    subject = charfield(default=1, choices = [1,2,3])
    people = ManyToManyField(ModelA, through="ModelAB", related_name="objects")
```

Then you can filter using that name.

```
ModelA.objects.filter(objects__status = 99)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it get confusing with the manager nme when doing a query?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean?